# NSDecimalNumber Rounding not working in iOS 11

Tags: rounding, nsdecimalnumber

I have an app that's been in the store since iOS 9.  Recently it just broke because of rounding errors. I'm using Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b).  I wrote a piece of text code that shows rounding working, in iOS 9, but not iOS 11.  The result should be rounded to 2 decimal places.

```
NSDecimalNumberHandler* round = [NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundPlain scale:2 raiseOnExactness:NO raiseOnOverflow:NO raiseOnUnderflow:NO raiseOnDivideByZero:YES];
NSDecimalNumber* myNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"67.95999999999997"];
NSDecimalNumber* result = [myNumber decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:round];
NSLog(@"myNumber = %@", myNumber);
NSLog(@"rounding result = %@", result);
```

**On iOS 11:**

myNumber = 67.95999999999997
rounding result = 67.96000000000001

**On iOS9 **
myNumber = 67.95999999999997
rounding result = 67.96

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE - Problem Solved**

This isn't a rounding error, but an issue with NSDecimalNumber's description method.  When I looked in the value, with the debugger, it's correct.

To see the correct result use:

```
NSLog(@"rounding result = %@", result.stringValue);
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! This saved my life, I don't know how much time I have spent trying to get this to work, and it was the log statement that was wrong :) Awesome